# Regex ignore space unicode (%20)

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to ignore a unicode character (white space) from a sentence and any help will be highly appreciated.

Example -

```
utmctr=google%20search%20keyword
```

Desired output -

```
google search keyword
```

I am trying to use `\p{Z}` to do this but to no avail.

Many Thanks

Comment: Well you don't want to ignore, you want to replace that %20 with a space... Also in your expected output you removed `utmctr=`, is this wanted behavior too?

Comment: Yes, I just need the search term. Thanks.

Comment: You're actually searching for `decodeURI`?

Comment: It's Java (look at the comments in my answer). I edited his question to add the tag. @thinkin_hydrogen: please next time specify the programming language if you want answers for a specific programming language.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to do 2 substitutions: remove the leading identifier `utmctr=` and substitute the `%20`, so you will need 2 steps:

1. Search: `"utmctr="`; Replace: `""`
2. Search: `%20`; Replace: `" "`

Depending on the language you're using (e.g. Perl) you need not the double quotes.

EDIT: since you're using Java:

```
String input = "utmctr=google%20search%20keyword"; 
String output = input.replaceAll("utmctr=", "").replaceAll("%20", " ");
```

`replaceAll()` uses regular expressions, but in your case you really don't need using special characters for regexes.

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm afraid all I have is a Regex front end tool with back language Java. I am using something like this - .*utmctr=(.*?); which gives me google%20search%20keyword.

Comment: That's no problem, mate. If it's Java, you can use `String.replaceAll()`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to remove the %20 in a string and replace it with a space, right? Then using `(%20)` as a regex should do it while using the global replace option (`g`), and replace it with a space.